# How to detect if a function has been defined locally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

In Python, I have a decorator that has to skip any real work if a function is defined locally in the one that calls it. I made a simple testing script:

```
def fn1():
    # @my_decorator will be here
    def fn2():
        pass

    print(fn2)
    return fn2

x = fn1()
print(x)
print(x.__module__)
```

It prints this:

```
 <function fn1.<locals>.fn2 at 0x7fd61bdf3ae8>
 <function fn1.<locals>.fn2 at 0x7fd61bdf3ae8>
 __main__
```

As I see, Python sees that the function is defined in a local space (`<locals>` in the printed text), but I can't see how I can find that bit of data. I walked through the `inspect` module, and don't see anything similar.

I can't rely on whether the function is in globals or not.

What do I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, the direct approach is to check if [the `CO_NESTED` flag is set on the function's code object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#code-objects-bit-flags):

```
import inspect

...

def is_nested(func):
    return func.__code__.co_flags & inspect.CO_NESTED

def deco(func):
    if is_nested(func):
        # This is a nested function, return it unchanged
        return func
    ... otherwise, do your decoration here ...
```

That said, there is another approach if what you care about is whether you've actually closed over anything. A function that doesn't use anything from the enclosing scope is nested, but not a closure, and that distinction is often important. So for example:

```
def foo(x):
    def bar(y):
        pass
    return bar
```

is *not* making a closure because `bar` makes use of no variables from the scope of the `foo` call. By contrast, even though it's a garbage reference, this *is* making a closure simply by reading the value of `x` from the enclosing scope:

```
def foo(x):
    def baz(y):
        x
    return baz
```

You can tell the difference between `bar` and `baz` by testing the `__closure__` attribute (which is `None` if no nested variables have been closed over) or by checking the `co_freevars` attribute of the `__code__` object (which is a tuple of names closed on, so if it's empty, then it's not a closure, though it may still be a nested function):

```
def is_closure(func):
    return func.__closure__ is not None
    # Or using documented names, since __closure__ isn't for some reason,
    # co_freevars is a tuple of names captured from nested scope
    return bool(func.__code__.co_freevars)

    # Or on 3.3+, you even get a function to aid you:
    return bool(inspect.getclosurevars(func).nonlocals)
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, here's a hacky approach:

```
'<locals>' in f.__qualname__
```

It seems brittle to me, though.

Another approach is to play with the `Frame`, but I like that even less, I think:

```
In [1]: import inspect

In [2]: def deco(f):
   ...:     try:
   ...:         frame = inspect.currentframe()
   ...:         print(frame.f_back.f_locals is globals())
   ...:     finally:
   ...:         del frame
   ...:     return f
   ...:

In [3]: @deco
   ...: def g(): pass
   ...:
True

In [4]: def f():
   ...:     @deco
   ...:     def g(): pass
   ...:

In [5]: f()
False
```

Comment: I think this is a legitimately good solution. `__qualname__` is also what's used (in CPython at least) to create the `repr` of the function, there's no other hidden attributes that it checks.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard yeah, I was playing around with `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals is globals()`, which seems to work too, but I like that even *less*.